# Python sockets: can send strings but can't send "outputs" (disconnect from socket)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, sockets, python-requests

I am a Python beginner and I'm coding this remote shell based on a central server and two clients (one who send commands and the other who receives them and send an output).

OS Is Windows 10 64bit and Python is 3.7.

If I send strings or simple variables from one to another it's ok, but when for example I want to send the output of file.read() or of a subprocess, I got disconnected from the central server with:

> You have been disconnected from the server

What I am missing here?

Server code:

```
import socket
import threading

#Variables for holding information about connections
connections = []
total_connections = 0

#Client class, new instance created for each connected client
#Each instance has the socket and address that is associated with items
#Along with an assigned ID and a name chosen by the client
class Client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, socket, address, id, name, signal):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket
        self.address = address
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.signal = signal

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " " + str(self.address)

    #Attempt to get data from client
    #If unable to, assume client has disconnected and remove him from server data
    #If able to and we get data back, print it in the server and send it back to every
    #client aside from the client that has sent it
    #.decode is used to convert the byte data into a printable string
    def run(self):
        while self.signal:
            try:
                data = self.socket.recv(1024)
            except:
                print("Client " + str(self.address) + " has disconnected")
                self.signal = False
                connections.remove(self)
                break
            if data != "":
                print("ID " + str(self.id) + ": " + str(data.decode("utf-8")))
                for client in connections:
                    if client.id != self.id:
                        client.socket.sendall(data)

#Wait for new connections
def newConnections(socket):
    while True:
        sock, address = socket.accept()
        global total_connections
        connections.append(Client(sock, address, total_connections, "Name", True))
        connections[len(connections) - 1].start()
        print("New connection at ID " + str(connections[len(connections) - 1]))
        total_connections += 1

def main():
    #Get host and port
    host = "192.168.1.240"
    port = 9876

    #Create new server socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen(5)

    #Create new thread to wait for connections
    newConnectionsThread = threading.Thread(target = newConnections, args = (sock,))
    newConnectionsThread.start()

main()
```

Code of the client that execute the commands and that get disconnected **there's a comment where it disconnect, it does the same with the output of file.read()**

```
import socket
import threading
import sys
import requests
import subprocess
import time

hisID = "Server:"

def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):

    bot_token = 'xxxxxx'
    bot_chatID = 'xxxxxx'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()

#Wait for incoming data from server
#.decode is used to turn the message in bytes to a string
def receive(socket, signal):
    while signal:
        try:
            data = socket.recv(1024)
            command = str(data.decode("utf-8"))
            print(command)
            if command == "oof":
                sock.sendall(str.encode("YOU TOLD ME TO oof?"))
                telegram_bot_sendtext("oof")
            elif command == "command": 
                out = subprocess.check_output("dir", shell=True)
                sock.sendall(str.encode(out)) #HERE I GOT DISCONNECTED
            else:
                sock.sendall(str.encode("Command not recognized"))
        except:
            print("You have been disconnected from the server")
            signal = False
            break

#Get host and port
host = "192.168.1.240"
port = 9876

#Attempt connection to server
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host, port))
except:
    print("Could not make a connection to the server")
    input("Press enter to quit")
    sys.exit(0)

#Create new thread to wait for data
receiveThread = threading.Thread(target = receive, args = (sock, True))
receiveThread.start()

#Send data to server
#str.encode is used to turn the string message into bytes so it can be sent across the network
while True:
    try:
        input()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        sock.close()
        sys.exit()
```

Code of the client who sends commands

```
import socket
import threading
import sys
hisID = "Client:"
#Wait for incoming data from server
#.decode is used to turn the message in bytes to a string
def receive(socket, signal):
    while signal:
        try:
            data = socket.recv(1024)
            command = str(data.decode("utf-8"))
            print(hisID + ">" + command )
        except:
            print("You have been disconnected from the server")
            signal = False
            break

#Get host and port
host = "192.168.1.240"
port = 9876

#Attempt connection to server
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host, port))
except:
    print("Could not make a connection to the server")
    input("Press enter to quit")
    sys.exit(0)

#Create new thread to wait for data
receiveThread = threading.Thread(target = receive, args = (sock, True))
receiveThread.start()

#Send data to server
#str.encode is used to turn the string message into bytes so it can be sent across the network
while True:
    message = input(":>")
    sock.sendall(str.encode(message))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bare `except` in your code is hiding a coding error.  Ideally, catch only errors you expect (socket errors use `OSError` as a base class) so unexpected errors aren't hidden.  You can add the exception reason to the error message as well.

```
except OSError as e:
    print(f"You have been disconnected from the server: {e}")
```

With this change you will clearly see the problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\client.py", line 34, in receive
    sock.sendall(str.encode(out)) #HERE I GOT DISCONNECTED
TypeError: descriptor 'encode' requires a 'str' object but received a 'bytes'
```

The bug fix is to use `sock.sendall(out)`.

Comment: thank you very much! Just because I'm a beginner, can I use another except block to catch all others exceptions?

Comment: @WyattGillette Yes, use a more general exception base class such as `except Exception as e:`.  Also see the `traceback` module, where you can still get a stack trace on failure as well.  It's all good information for debugging.